# VBA to create running list of values based on same cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells (R5 and S5) that are aggregates based on a RAND() function. I want to create a running list of those values, which change every time the sheet recalculates. The list should have about 100K iterations of this. I wrote a "dumb" bit of VBA that copy/pastes the values into a list.

This does sort of work, but is too slow to scale to 100k iterations and I get a gap every 50 records for some reason.

There must be a better / faster way to do this with a loop or something like that? TIA.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("R5:S5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("U5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("U6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("U7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Calculate

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Macro2 Me
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    lCell.Resize(, 2).Value = ws.Range("R5:S5").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I get an error with "Argument not Optional" - any pointers?